# Send Opentelemetry tracing data to influxdb bucket

Tags: node.js, influxdb, trace, open-telemetry

How to send tracing data of nodejs endpoint from opentelemetry to influxdb bucket so that we can see the trace metrics in graffana dashboard.

I am not able to understand the code for this that how to transfer the data to influxdb so that can see the trace metrics graph on grafana.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.